# How to print the string without formatting in python?

Tags: python, string

Is there any possibility or way to print the string with out passing any arguments or without formatting in python?

**To  @Blender.**

I have done an simple script using mysqlDB module to interact with the mysql server.
Using that script i can execute the mysql query to get the output of it.

For an example, if i pass the input  as " show master logs " into the script  i am getting the error as

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.

Here i cannot pass the enough  agrumnet to print the output. Because, if i pass the enough argument to print the output, the i cannot print the output of query which has more argument. So, i want to print the output without any argument.

It is possible or any alternative solution is there, suggest me. I am learner in python

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I can't see what you mean by "without formatting".

Comment: @Blender For example, if i get the ouptput from query such as  " select * mysql.user " and " show databases " all output query has different format. So, i need to print those  output   without any formatting .

Comment: Hmm, I still can't see what you mean by "format". Can you post what happens and what should happen?

Comment: I have found the solution, by using .fetchall()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just print it:

```
>>> print "hello %s"
hello %s
```

No formatting occurs, as opposed to:

```
>>> print "hello %s" % "there"
hello there
```